# Enable orientation in Windows Phone 8.0 application

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone application development. I am developing application for windows 8.0.  I cannot find file [Package.appxmanifest] in the project.

Is there a setting in application that turns on orientation? Because when I rotate my phone my controls stay same in potrait mode.

Can any one guide me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Package.appxmanifest` is a WP8.1 runtime thing.  For WP 8.0, it's `AppManifest` and `WMAppManifest`.  You can find it under Properties under the project Solution.

[image]

---

As for orientation, click your MainPage.xaml and select your `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>` tag.  Under Common, you can change your Orientations.

[image]

And here's a Quick Start Guide in handling Orientation Changes: [Quickstart: Screen orientation for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207002%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In your designer page there will be a property named SupportedOrientations. You can change that to Portrait, Landscape or PortraitOrLandscape for both.

While developing if you want to change the orientation use Orientation property.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="TemplateSwitcher.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"    
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
```